# How do I set proxy for chrome in python webdriver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, proxy, webdriver

I'm using this code:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "proxy.server.address")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", "port_number")
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

to set proxy for FF in python webdriver. This works for FF. How to set proxy like this in Chrome? I found this [exmaple](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#using-a-proxy) but is not very helpful. When I run the script nothing happens (Chrome browser is not started).

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but did you change the `Firefox` lines to their Chrome equivalents? Could you post your code?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "nothing happens?" Is there an error message? An exit status of any kind?

Comment: I noticed that if I have a proxy set in Internet Explorer the script is not working (FF is opening but fails on driver.get("google.com/";)). There no error messages, it refuse to connect. The script is working if there are no proxy settings enabled in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 116):

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: Error : 
`WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate username/password proxy authentication into this example?

Comment: I am stuck at this too @Liquidgenius. Can you help me out

Comment: @SajjadZaidi Apologies it has been a while and I don’t remember how I solved this.

Comment: See the comments below for an answer to the username/password thing

Answer (score 17):

Its working for me...

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: how do you add username/password if proxy need sauthen?

Comment: I imagine you would pass the username and password in the arguments, would be about looking up what the argument key would be for bot and populate as desired

Comment: You'd add them in the url: `scheme://user:pass@my.great.host:port`

Answer (score 8):

I had an issue with the same thing.  ChromeOptions is very weird because it's not integrated with the desiredcapabilities like you would think.  I forget the exact details, but basically ChromeOptions will reset to default certain values based on whether you did or did not pass a desired capabilities dict.

I did the following monkey-patch that allows me to specify my own dict without worrying about the complications of ChromeOptions

change the following code in /selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:

```
def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=0,
             chrome_options=None, service_args=None,
             desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None, skip_capabilities_update=False):
    """
    Creates a new instance of the chrome driver.

    Starts the service and then creates new instance of chrome driver.

    :Args:
     - executable_path - path to the executable. If the default is used it assumes the executable is in the $PATH
     - port - port you would like the service to run, if left as 0, a free port will be found.
     - desired_capabilities: Dictionary object with non-browser specific
       capabilities only, such as "proxy" or "loggingPref".
     - chrome_options: this takes an instance of ChromeOptions
    """
    if chrome_options is None:
        options = Options()
    else:
        options = chrome_options

    if skip_capabilities_update:
        pass
    elif desired_capabilities is not None:
        desired_capabilities.update(options.to_capabilities())
    else:
        desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()

    self.service = Service(executable_path, port=port,
        service_args=service_args, log_path=service_log_path)
    self.service.start()

    try:
        RemoteWebDriver.__init__(self,
            command_executor=self.service.service_url,
            desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
    except:
        self.quit()
        raise 
    self._is_remote = False
```

all that changed was the "skip_capabilities_update" kwarg. Now I just do this to set my own dict:

```
capabilities = dict( DesiredCapabilities.CHROME )

if not "chromeOptions" in capabilities:
    capabilities['chromeOptions'] = {
        'args' : [],
        'binary' : "",
        'extensions' : [],
        'prefs' : {}
    }

capabilities['proxy'] = {
    'httpProxy' : "%s:%i" %(proxy_address, proxy_port),
    'ftpProxy' : "%s:%i" %(proxy_address, proxy_port),
    'sslProxy' : "%s:%i" %(proxy_address, proxy_port),
    'noProxy' : None,
    'proxyType' : "MANUAL",
    'class' : "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    'autodetect' : False
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path="path_to_chrome", desired_capabilities=capabilities, skip_capabilities_update=True )
```

Answer (score 7):

It's easy!

First, define your proxy url

```py
proxy_url = "127.0.0.1:9009"
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': proxy_url,
    'sslProxy': proxy_url,
    'noProxy': ''})
```

Then, create chrome capability settings and add proxy to them

```py
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
```

Finally, create the webdriver and pass the desired capabilities

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("http://example.org")
```

All together it looks like this

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

proxy_url = "127.0.0.1:9009"
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': proxy_url,
    'sslProxy': proxy_url,
    'noProxy': ''})

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("http://example.org")
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me like a charm:

```
proxy = "localhost:8080"
desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
desired_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": proxy,
    "ftpProxy": proxy,
    "sslProxy": proxy,
    "noProxy": None,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect": False
}
```

Comment: Where are the login credentials?

Answer (score 5):

For people out there asking how to setup proxy server in chrome which needs authentication should follow these steps.

1. Create a proxy.py file in  your project, use this [code](https://gist.github.com/rajat-np/5d901702a33e7b4b5132b1acee5d778e) and call proxy_chrome from
   proxy.py everytime you need it. You need to pass parameters like proxy server, port and username password for authentication.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import zipfile,os

def proxy_chrome(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT,PROXY_USER,PROXY_PASS):
    manifest_json = """
            {
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "manifest_version": 2,
                "name": "Chrome Proxy",
                "permissions": [
                    "proxy",
                    "tabs",
                    "unlimitedStorage",
                    "storage",
                    "<all_urls>",
                    "webRequest",
                    "webRequestBlocking"
                ],
                "background": {
                    "scripts": ["background.js"]
                },
                "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
            }
            """

    background_js = """
    var config = {
            mode: "fixed_servers",
            rules: {
              singleProxy: {
                scheme: "https",
                host: "%(host)s",
                port: parseInt(%(port)d)
              },
              bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
            }
          };
    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});
    function callbackFn(details) {
        return {
            authCredentials: {
                username: "%(user)s",
                password: "%(pass)s"
            }
        };
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                callbackFn,
                {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                ['blocking']
    );
        """ % {
            "host": PROXY_HOST,
            "port": PROXY_PORT,
            "user": PROXY_USER,
            "pass": PROXY_PASS,
        }


    pluginfile = 'extension/proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

    with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
        zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
        zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)

    co = Options()
    #extension support is not possible in incognito mode for now
    #co.add_argument('--incognito')
    co.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    #disable infobars
    co.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    co.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["ignore-certificate-errors"])
    #location of chromedriver, please change it according to your project.
    chromedriver = os.getcwd()+'/Chromedriver/chromedriver'
    co.add_extension(pluginfile)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver,chrome_options=co)
    #return the driver with added proxy configuration.
    return driver
```

Comment: great. that's the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: For anyone else who might have the same issue as me, this solution wasn't working because I had to change scheme: "https" to "http". Worked after that :)

Answer (score -14):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

myProxy = "86.111.144.194:3128"
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy':''})

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get('http://whatismyip.com')
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Chrome - the question was about Chrome

Comment: answer for chrome