# How to handle proxy authentication window in robot framework? Any solution other than AutoIt?

Tags: python, proxy, robotframework, basic-authentication

I'm working in Robot framework using python and when the application URL is launched, a proxy authentication pop up is displayed. Is there any way to handle this in Robot framework?

--Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918261/how-do-you-configure-your-chrome-browser-to-pass-through-a-proxy-in-selenium2lib

As suggested in one of the answers, try to use scheme://user:pass@server:port as the import proxy and it should work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.