# How to run python-selenium with proxy settings

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, remotewebdriver

I'm implementing a selenium - python code to scrape through a webpage. I was able to run the program using remote webdriver without any proxy wall. However I need to run this behind a proxy wall. I couldn't figure out whether to user Proxy class or to implement proxy using Desired Capabilities? 
Attaching the current code without any proxy settings 
PS. using a DOM object model

```
from driver import Webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy
import unittest,time
desired_capabilities = { 'browserName' : 'chrome' }
command_executor = "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
proxy_address = 'http://proxy-chain.companyname.com:911'

from base import Login_page


class testing_first_code(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp (self):
     self.driver = Webdriver(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities, command_executor=command_executor )
```

Comment: Did you try `self.driver = Webdriver(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities, command_executor=command_executor, proxy=proxy_address)` ?

Comment: @Arun I tried this but im getting the following error    : str' object has no attribute 'add_to_capabilities'

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver/24237188#24183276 ?

Comment: I tried this way.  
`desired_capabilities = { 'browserName' : 'chrome' }
proxy_address = Proxy( { 'proxyType' :  ProxyType.MANUAL,
      'httpProxy' : 'http://proxy-chain.companyname.com:911',
      'ftpProxy'  :  'http://proxy-chain.companynamel.com:911',
      'noProxy'   :  None,
      'autodetect':  False 
        }
    )

class testing_first_code(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp (self):
        self.driver = Webdriver(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities, command_executor=command_executor, proxy=proxy_address )`

Comment: Now getting error  A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"