# Selenium Webdrive Proxy - C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to enable a proxy on running Google Chrome (for example after I log in to my mail)?

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible:

```
PROXY = "proxy-here" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

[how do i set proxy for chrome in python webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver)

Comment: It's not working ... I am using the following code for C#

`IWebDriver driverGC = new ChromeDriver();

driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://whatismyipaddress.com");

Thread.Sleep(5000);

 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

 var proxy = new Proxy();

 proxy.HttpProxy = "71.54.128.150:47035";

 options.Proxy = proxy;

 Thread.Sleep(5000);

 driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://whatismyipaddress.com");

 Thread.Sleep(5000);`

Comment: I need to pass or exclude this `driverGC = new ChromeDriver();`, because it's loading a new chrome driver and it's not fetching the login details.