# Chrome WebDriver hangs with "Waiting for all views" in python testing

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

All types of methods I used to handle the chrome web driver, but I am unable to do so. In normal It's loading perfectly, I am not facing any issues. Only during automation chrome driver is loading and waiting for all views. Please help me out guys.

Comment: what version of chromedriver and chrome browser you are using?

Comment: Update the question with your _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Comment: @Chanda Korat - 
version - ChromeDriver v2.27
Chrome browser- Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @DebanjanB -- I did not get any error message, after waiting some time browser still loading, after that, I clear cookies and I got below error message --
E
check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.117)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
Ran 1 test in 319.263s

Comment: @Shibu Plz use latest chromedriver version which is 2.38. May be this can solve your issue.

Comment: @Chanda -- Now am using latest one , but same issue --
chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7

Comment: Try setting proxy as null. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver)