# How to setup private proxy with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i want to use private proxy for testing. 
I tried this one, but it is not working

https://botproxy.net/docs/how-to/setting-chromedriver-proxy-auth-with-selenium-using-python/

Comment: hope it will help :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver

Comment: add some code which you tried.

Comment: same as describe here https://botproxy.net/docs/how-to/setting-chromedriver-proxy-auth-with-selenium-using-python/

Comment: how about this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40628176/10566062

Comment: is this works for private proxy, if then how.