# Setting the region in the Python Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, discord.py, steam, regional-settings

I'm currently making a program which fetches the prices and discounts etc. off the Steam sales search page, however all the prices are in $ and I need them to be in £. I'm relatively new to Python and Selenium, and have been unable to fix the issue myself, and I haven't seen anyone else with a similar problem.

I'm using the Selenium webdriver, and don't know how to configure its region, but I'm assuming that it'll probably need to be something inputted into Chrome Options, but I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&cc=US` or `&currency=1` to url. I can't tell which will work if you dont give specific url.
Can you give an example url?

Comment: Sorry, I should've put the link in before. It's the Steam Store search page: ' https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1 '.
Previously, I had tried the &cc=Country part and it hadn't worked. I decided to try it again now, and it worked. They must have changed the way it worked or something because this never worked before.
Thanks for the response and the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proxy servers for this as mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver):

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

Comment: I've tried this with the program I wrote and also tried running it on its own, and it doesn't seem to work. I've tried proxy addresses for the US and UK and neither have worked, just telling me that there is no internet connection - I don't know if this is a problem with the code or that the proxies are down.