# How to set proxy on cmd or python for windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, proxy

can anyone help me about this? I just wanna set up a proxy with cmd or python. I have tried these but it doesn't work.

First try(on cmd):

```
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-ip:proxy-port
```

Output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:
    Proxy Server(s) :  proxy-ip:proxy-port
    Bypass List     :  (none)
```

I checked my ip on web site. Nothing changed.

Second try:

```
import os
import requests

os.system('netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-ip:proxy-port')

r = requests.get("https://ipinfo.io/")

print(r.text)
```

Stil nothing changed. What i need to do?

Comment: Are you trying to change your OS proxy or do you want to send request using with proxyied python? because these have different solutions.

Comment: @SezerBOZKIR Hayır proxy ile request göndermek istemiyorum. OS'a proxy kurmak istiyorum. Tıpkı manuel, el ile giriyoruz ya ağ ayarlarından onun gibi.

Answer (score 0):

When you need something major changes on OS, you should provide admin permissions, here is the solution;

```
pip install elevate
```

And you can use this code;

```
import os
from elevate import elevate

elevate(show_console=False)

command = 'netsh winhttp set proxy proxy_ip:proxy_port bypass-list="localhost"'
os.system(command)
```

You can look at the details of [elevate](https://pypi.org/project/elevate/) package.

Comment: I already tried, nothing changed. Could it be that Chrome is ignoring the windows proxy settings? If so why is it accepting when I manually change the proxy setting.

Comment: If you are trying to change Selenium Chrome, you can look at here;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver  


If you want to change desktop application, you should start with like this command;
google-chrome --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"

or you have to change the chrome default settings file;
https://superuser.com/questions/149032/where-is-the-chrome-settings-file

Comment: Above code is not selenium, dude. As you can see. Also I know using proxy with selenium it's super easy but i cant change my all test bot to selenium. I just wanna set proxy to Window's all run. Everyone saying this code 'netsh winhttp set proxy proxy_ip:proxy_port bypass-list="localhost"' but it doesnt work.

Comment: I succeed. I don't need help anymore. Your answer is right for someone but not for me. Should I accept it answer? Maybe someone see this answer and can find solution for itself.

Comment: Yes it will be usefull, also please add your solution to your question, we should support the future :)